# Entity Framework Core: default value when migrating nullable column to required

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `datetime2` column that used to be `nullable`.
We now need this column to be set so we want to set it as required and migrate the column with a default value of 1970-1-1.

I have created the migration and edited the migration-file to the following:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "Start",
            table: "Project",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
            oldType: "datetime2",
            oldNullable: true, 
            defaultValue: new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
    }
```

I have manually added the `defaultValue: new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));` line.

Unfortunately, when updating the database I get the following error:

> 2021-03-22 10:12:55.5398: Error occurred in "UpdateDatabase":
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Start', table 'dbo.Project'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
> The statement has been terminated.

I have also tried to set the value via `defaultValueSql` but the same error occurs:

```
defaultValueSql: "'1970-1-1'"
```

Why does the defaultValue not work, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

btw: this is the script that gets executed:

```
DECLARE @var0 sysname;
SELECT @var0 = [d].[name]
FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Project]') AND [c].[name] = N'Start');
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [Project] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [Project] ALTER COLUMN [Start] datetime2 NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE [Project] ADD DEFAULT '1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000' FOR [Start];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make an existing column `required` in DB you need to make sure there is no null value in the column. in order to fix that, update the table and fill the column with a value.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE Project SET Start = GETDATE() WHERE Start is null");
 migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
        name: "Start",
        table: "Project",
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
        oldType: "datetime2",
        oldNullable: true, 
        defaultValue: new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
```